# How do I use the digit-by-digit square root algorithm in a base-n context, e.g. $2^{16}$?

Tags: algorithms

I have to take the square root of a number so large that there is no way to compute it directly. I thought if I divided it up into smaller pieces, I might be able to get this done in as few steps as possible.
I found the [digit-by-digit square root algoritm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation) on Wikipedia, and thought it might be useful. The page stated that it works for any base, but it didn't give a general way to apply it to an arbitrary base-$n$.

How do I implement it in base-$65536$, for example? And does this allow me to speed it up by taking the square root of the individual pairs of base-$65536$ digits using some `sqrt` function already available to me?

My focus is mainly on the math behind the algorithm. Is the algorithm suitable to a base-$2^{16}$ context, or do I gain no advantage over binary, for example?

Comment: The algorithm based on single bits is surprisingly fast since it avoids divisions and multiplications of digit-sized integers and replaces them by bit-shifting. This may be a reason that you do not find the other variants explained in detail. The digit based algorithm is about as fast (or here slow) as Newton's method. -- The generalized root computation is explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth_root_algorithm

Comment: If you just want the square root you should probably use something like newtons method.

Comment: @Darksonn I'm afraid that for extremely large numbers, Newton's method may take longer to converge. This algorithm also represents each digit exactly.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink If you pick a proper approximation newtons method should have quadratic convergence, regardless how large the number is. Also, what kind large is this number? Maybe post the number on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Darksonn I not only need to check one extremely large number, I need to check a whole lot of them! The truth is I have no idea what numbers I'll have to check, just that they'll eventually get really huge!

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Newtons method works fine on large numbers if you have some kind of unbounded number type. You can expect to have the correct number of digits double every iteration with newtons method.

Comment: I will say that I plan to check the square root of $5(a^3+b^3)^2\pm~4$ for arbitrarily high $a,b$.